# dojo/request PUT method dosn't work

Tags: javascript, python, django, dojo

I have a web app using Python Django and Dojo framework.
I wanna send a PUT request from Dojo (using dojo/request) to server Django but when server receives a request, the data within are empty and validate Invalid.
BUT when I change method from PUT to POST, it's work correctly.

Here is my code:

```
_save: function(data){
        var idForm = "editForm" + this.id;
        var value = dijit.byId(idForm).get('value');
        console.log(value);
        request.put("/api/guestbook/"+this.bookName+"/greeting/"+this.id+"/", {
            data: {
                book_name: this.bookName,
                message: value.message
            },
            headers: { "X-CSRFToken": _cookie('csrftoken') }
        }).then(lang.hitch(this, function(text){

        }));
    },
```

And in Django:

```
def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.get_form(self.form_class)
    logging.warning(form)
    logging.warning(request.PUT)
    if form.is_valid():
        logging.warning("This form is VALID")
    else:
        logging.warning("This form is INVALID!!!")
```

Anyone can help me?
Thanks for help!

Comment: Pls help me to resolve it, I need it in my probation :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the way to receive PUT method below:

```
def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    request.PUT = QueryDict(request.body)
    form = self.form_class(request.PUT)
    if form.is_valid():
        logging.warning("This form is VALID")
    else:
        logging.warning("This form is INVALID")
```

This is ok :)

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing from your X-CSRFToken header that you are doing cross domain requests, i.e. [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/).

If you look in your browser's console, you'll probably see an OPTIONS request being sent to the server. This is called a "preflight request", and your server needs to respond with CORS headers telling the browser that it's okay to make the cross domain PUT request.

In your case, you want the server to respond with headers similar to:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://your-site-hostname-and-port
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-CSRFToken
```

Simple POST requests do not need the preflight OPTIONS request, that's probably why it works. A pretty good tutorial on html5rocks [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/).